# How to install Ruby 2.4.0 on Mac OS using RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm unable to install Ruby 2.4.0.

- RVM version is 1.29.1
- Rubygems version is 2.6.11

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.4.0 using:

```
rvm install ruby-2.4.0
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.4.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
Installing requirements for osx_brew.
Updating system...........
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.4.0',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/bbc-admin/.rvm/log/1492510247_ruby-2.4.0/update_system.log
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.'
++ rvm_pretty_print stderr
++ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think you may need to update Homebrew; try `brew update` and then re-try the `rvm install ruby-2.4.0` command.

I would have added this as a comment but not enough rep. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: tried this.. got this error :


`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 Library/Formula/libimobiledevice.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: check this [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/11448). It might solve your problem.

Comment: In terms of your error, you need to run `git stash` and then `brew update` in order to not have any files be overwritten